# Numbers of ways to make a committee of three from a group 0f 20 students

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways out of $20$ students you can select $1$ treasurer, $1$ secretary and $3$ more representatives?

I understand that for single selections I can multiply with the availability of the persons. Like for treasurer I can have $20$ options, for secretary then I have $19$ options. So I can select a secretary and a treasurer in $20\cdot 19$ ways. but for $3$ more representatives? Should I multiply up to $16$? This is exactly where I am stuck.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a rather simple problem where there are 20 ways to select treasurer and 19 for secretary as a starting point though please show some work here as it helps to know where you are stuck as this isn't a homework doing site.

Comment: I will help @mahfuz_fahim by editing the post.

Comment: I understand that for single selections I can multiply with the availability of the persons. like for treasurer I can have 20 options, for secretary then I have 19 options. So I can select a secretary and a treasurer in 20*19 ways. but for 3 more representatives? should I multiply upto 16? this is exactly where I am stuck JB King

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should include your work on the problem and indicate where you are stuck in the statement of your question so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that since the treasurer can be selected in $20$ ways and the secretary can be selected in $19$ ways, the number of ways of selecting the treasurer and secretary is $20 \cdot 19$.

It remains to select three representatives.  There are $18$ ways to pick the first representative, $17$ ways to third the second representative, and $16$ ways to pick the third representative.  However, $18 \cdot 17 \cdot 16$ overcounts the number of ways we can pick the representatives.  Suppose that the three selected representatives are Amelia, Bruce, and Cynthia.  Notice that the following selections produce the same representatives:

Amelia, Bruce, Cynthia
Amelia, Cynthia, Bruce
Bruce, Amelia, Cynthia
Bruce, Cynthia, Amelia
Cynthia, Amelia, Bruce
Cynthia, Bruce, Amelia

For any given selection of three particular representatives, there are three ways to pick the first representative, two ways to pick the second, and one way to pick the third, so there are $3! = 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 6$ orders in which we can pick the same three representatives.  Thus, the number of ways of selecting the three representatives is 
$$\frac{18 \cdot 17 \cdot 16}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}  = \frac{18 \cdot 17 \cdot 16}{3!} \cdot \frac{15!}{15!} = \frac{18!}{3!15!} = \binom{18}{3}$$
where
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
is the number of ways of selecting a subset of $k$ elements from a set of $n$ elements, that is, of making an unordered selection of $k$ of the $n$ elements.  The number $\binom{n}{k}$ is called the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) since it is the coefficient of $x^{n - k}y^k$ in the binomial expansion $(x + y)^n$.

Getting back to your question, the number of ways of selecting a committee consisting of a treasurer, secretary, and three representatives from a class of $20$ students is $$20 \cdot 19 \cdot \binom{18}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

There are $20\choose 1$ options for the treasurer. Assuming one students can't have multiple roles, we have $19\choose 1$ options for the secretary and $18\choose 3$ options for the representatives, making the total number of possibilities $20\cdot 19\cdot 816=310080$.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I would guess the person asking the question hasn't been exposed to binomial numbers. You may want to go into detail as to how to calculate them and what they count.